# Go mod replace dependency with private fork

Tags: git, go, go-modules

I added the dependency to `go.mod`:

```
require (
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.3.1
)

replace (
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 => example.com/echo/v4.git v4.3.1
)
```

And getting error like `replace example.com/echo.git: version "v4.3.1" invalid: module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v4`. Tag with the required version exists in the repo.

While I'm tried to play with the version I got something like `v1.2.1-0.20210520145606-2defe74d39f0`, but when I set my replace section like:

```
replace (
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 => example.com/echo/v4.git v1.2.1-0.20210520145606-2defe74d39f0
)
```

I'm getting the error `errno=Connection refused` related to the private git server.

Could you please advise what I'm doing wrong and how I can replace dependency with my private fork?

Comment: I think you don't need to specify the `.git`

Comment: @Matteo without `.git` I also get an error: `version "v4.3.1" invalid: unknown revision echo/v4.3.1`

Comment: Is the name of your repo actually `v4.git`? The `v4` part of the import path is only a tag in the original repo, it does not correspond to an actual path or repo name.

Comment: @JimB This is what me confusing also. If I change `replace` section to this `github.com/labstack/echo => bucket.digitalarsenal.net/elpaso/backend/libs/echo v4.3.1` it doesn't help also. `replace example.com/echo: version "v4.3.1" invalid: unknown revision libs/echo/v4.3.1`. But tag with this version exists.

Comment: @Ole I guess that error is actually from sum.golang.org. I’ve left an answer to that effect but if not please [edit] with the full output from running `go get`.

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure your repo path is accurate. v4.git means the repo is called v4; if that’s true that’s ok, but if not replace it with the correct name of the repo and keep the v4.x.x tag after it.
- If the fork is private it’s probably not accessible by sum.golang.org. Make sure GOPRIVATE is set to your private fork so Go does not try to get the checksum.

  ```
  go env -w GOPRIVATE=example.com
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! When I specified the correct path to the repo without any wired suffices in replace section `github.com/labstack/echo/v4 => example.com/echo.git v4.3.1` I got an error: `replace example.com/echo.git: version "v4.3.1" invalid: module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v4`. Tag 4.3.1 exists in the repo, I doublecheck this.

Comment: In my forks `go.mod` file I have `module github.com/labstack/echo/v4`

Answer (score 2):

If the replacement repo is hosted in a Git repository at `example.com/echo`, then the path to the replacement should probably be `example.com/echo.git/v4`:

```
replace (
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.3.1 => example.com/echo.git/v4 v4.3.1
)
```

If the `example.com` server serves [`go-import` metadata](https://golang.org/ref/mod#vcs-find), then you may be able to omit the `.git` suffix entirely:

```
replace (
    github.com/labstack/echo/v4 v4.3.1 => example.com/echo/v4 v4.3.1
)
```